# Android RelativeLayout set transparent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with `ProgressBar` and i'd like to set RelativeLayout transparent, using `android:background="@null"`. It works well, but not for android 5.1.0 and higher versions.

Here's the file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null">
    <ProgressBar style="@style/progress_bar_style"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So, I've tried some methods like

```
android:background="#00000000"
android:background="#77000000"
android:background="#AARRGGBB"
```

e.t.c i've found at stackoverflow. 
So, how to resolve this problem?

**UPDATE:**

[The trouble's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUIWD.png)

Comment: in `android 5.1.0 and higher versions`, what color of your `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Is this completely different layout?

Comment: why don't you use alpha?

Comment: it's all code i have for this layout.

Comment: what happens if you give different color rather then `@null`I.e Red or something else?

Comment: @vrund purohit it is getting the same color as a described

Answer (score 1):

your below code is working fine on Api > 21.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null">
    <ProgressBar style="@style/progress_bar_style"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**UpDate :**

you have to `clean` the project and `rebuild` it. May this will work.

Comment: if i set alpha to my layout it changes  transparency of my progressbar, not layout. maybe i need to add one more layout and do some magic there. gonna try

Comment: @pligosv your code work fine can you just `clean` and `rebuild` your project may be it's work.

Comment: @pligosv click on `Build Menu` and then click on `Clean Project`.

Answer (score -1):

i face the same problem in some days 
u can give color to relativelayout with java code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/rlayout">
```

in Java File u give colro

```
RelativeLayout ln = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayout);
    ln.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try set for your RelativeLayout background:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/yourRelativeLayoutID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bg_relative">
```

> Add bg_relative color in your colors.xml

```
<color name="bg_relative">#80795548</color>

and here 80 is transparency code, you can change like following,
```

100% — FF

95% — F2

90% — E6

85% — D9

80% — CC

75% — BF

70% — B3

65% — A6

60% — 99

55% — 8C

50% — 80

45% — 73

40% — 66

35% — 59

30% — 4D

25% — 40

20% — 33

15% — 26

10% — 1A

5% — 0D

0% — 00